# Noob looking for someone to check ERD

Tags: database-design, erd

I am a NOOB and am designing a relatively basic site.

I was wondering if anyone knows where I could get my ERD for the database objects checked out.

I know this is critical to the type of application I am designing and could use some help to make sure I have not overlooked anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more skilled colleague would be the best choice I think. Alternatively you can ask for a review on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

If you have a specific code problem you can post it here on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com).